# Case Sensitive in Google Sheets with REGEXMATCH

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am quite lost, I have read too much about REGEXMATCH on Google Sheets.
I am not an expert and I need help.

I have a spreadsheet in Google where I have implemented the REGEXMATCH formula to compare if a text appears between 2 cells.

I try to use the (?i) flag but can't get it to ignore the case.

Example:

```
=REGEXMATCH(F3;"(?i)I3")
```

Cell F3 has the text "Digital transformation | Jhonny"

- note capitalization in Digital

Cell I3 has the text "digital transformation"

- note that digital is in lower case

My formula returns FALSE because F3 has "Digital" and I3 has "digital".

How can I do please?

Thanks, it's my first post here.

Comment: You can do it another way, but the problem is that `REGEXMATCH` requires a full string match, so use `=REGEXMATCH(F3;"(?i).*I3.*")`

Comment: thanks Wiktor for your message !, I have tried to replace my formula with:
=REGEXMATCH(F3;"(?i).*I3.*")
and is still FALSE when it should be TRUE.
Any other idea?

Comment: Ah, you placed the cell address into a string, that is the problem. `=REGEXMATCH(F3;"(?i).*" & I3 & ".*")` will work. Note it will stop working once there are special chars in `I3` text. So, you'd better not use a regex here.

Comment: I didn't understand the syntax (I'm new) but this has worked, I really appreciate your time. @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1):

Note that the 2nd parameter of `REGEXMATCH()` expects a string. Right now you do mention "I3" in a literal form, hence the engine will try to literally match this. Therefor you need to concatenate the actuall cell's value into the equation:

```
=REGEXMATCH(F3;"(?i).*\b"&I3&"\b.*")
```

- `(?i)` - Match remainder case-insensitive.
- `.*\b` - Match 0+ characters upto a word-boundary.
- `"&I3&"` - This is the part where we insert the value from cell `I3`.
- `\b.*` - Another word-boundary and 0+ characters.

---

If you do not care about these word-boundaries for a better and more exact match, you do not need `REGEXMATCH()` at all (since it will also be slower than other functions). Therefor try:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(I3,F3))
```

Answer (score 0):

`I3` is a cell address, it must be concatenated with the strings, for example, with an ampersand.

Simply use

```js
=REGEXMATCH(F3,"(?i).*" & REGEXREPLACE(I3, "([-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}])", "\\$1") & ".*")
```

With `REGEXREPLACE(F4, "([-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}])", "\\$1")`, all special characters will be prepared for use in a regular expression.

The `(?i)` makes the expression case insensitive.